# Login with Facebook on Android app with Laravel passport authentication

Tags: android, laravel, facebook-graph-api, oauth-2.0, laravel-passport

I am working on one project in which I need I need functionality to log in with facebook and google on the android app.

`Android` app developer will send me the access token on `facebook`.

Now I want to handle that request with `Laravel` passport authentication. Like if the user is already there then return the `authentication token` or else create the new user and store login type as `facebook`.

Can any please help me by giving me an exact idea how to achieve it or some demo or library refresh anything.

Thanks

Comment: You can use Laravel Socialite to Authenticate with OAuth Providers like Facebook, Google, etc https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/socialite

Comment: @AzisAbdulBachar Thanks for answering but this Socialite seems for Web-based auth... I want to apply the same concept to the android app. So can you have an idea about that? Your help would be appreciable :)

Comment: You use client-server based app right? then you can use that concept to the Android app, that library is for handle the token that sent from android app

Comment: @AzisAbdulBachar yes now you got me. So that is what I am asking, I am getting token from the android app now how to handle that with socialite and return the needed stuff? I am new to laravel so no so much idea about the same. Can you please explain a bit ? or do you have any demo code ?Thanks :)

Comment: @SunilKushwaha Did you find the solution?